# Can a subquery inside a SELECT return multiple rows?

Tags: java, sql

I have the following code:

```
for (Project project : projectRepository.findAllWithoutEmployee()) {
  for (DailyEntry dailyEntry : dailyEntryRepository.findMinimalisticDailyEntryByProjectId(project.getId())){
     // do something
  }
}
```

The queries:

```
  @Query("SELECT new de.hiqs.project.Project(project.id, project.name, project.budget, " +
          "project.description, project.isArchived, project.archivedDate, " +
          "project.creationDate, project.customer.name) " +
          "FROM  Project project")
  List<Project> findAllWithoutEmployee();

  @Query("SELECT new de.hiqs.dailyentry.DailyEntry(dailyEntry.date, dailyEntry.startTime, dailyEntry.endTime, dailyEntry.status)" +
          "FROM DailyEntry dailyEntry " +
          "WHERE dailyEntry.id = :id")
  List<DailyEntry> findMinimalisticDailyEntryByProjectId(@Param("id") Long id)
```

So im calling the first query once to get all projects. Then im calling the second query n-times if n is the number of projects. Is there a way to combine both queries in one query so i dont have to send so many queries to a remote database? I would need to somehow get a list of `dailyEntries` as an attribute from the first query, but i do not think thats possible, because that isnt a field im persisting in the database. `DailyEntry` has a `OneToMany` relation to `Project`.

**Edit:**

I tried doing something like this:

```
  @Query("SELECT new de.hiqs.project.Project(project.id, project.name, project.budget, " +
          "project.description, project.isArchived, project.archivedDate, " +
          "project.creationDate, project.customer.name, (SELECT dailyEntry.id FROM DailyEntry dailyEntry)) " +
          "FROM  Project project")
  List<Project> findAllWithoutEmployee();
```

But im getting the error `ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`. So isnt it possible to use a subquery which returns multiple rows inside a SELECT statement?

**Edit2:**

My entities:

Project:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = {"employees"})
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Project {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private String name;

  private Integer budget;

  private String description;

  private Boolean isArchived;

  private LocalDate archivedDate;

  private LocalDate creationDate;
}
```

DailyEntry:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class DailyEntry {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  private LocalDate date;
  private LocalTime startTime;
  private LocalTime endTime;
  private Duration breaks;
  private String performanceRecord;
  private EntryStatus status;

  @ManyToOne
  private Project project;

  @ManyToOne
  private Employee employee;
}
```

Comment: You can use sub-query such as `SELECT ... from dailyEntry WHERE dailyEntry.id IN (SELECT project.id from Project)`

Comment: I tried this and a similar sub-query `(SELECT dailyEntry.id FROM DailyEntry dailyEntry WHERE dailyEntry.project.id = project.id))`. But im getting the error `Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [de.hiqs.project.Project]. Expected arguments are: long, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, boolean, java.time.LocalDate, java.time.LocalDate, java.lang.String, long`. So he thinks that subquery returns a long(last type) instead of an array of longs for some reason.

Comment: Move the sub-query to the FROM list instead, and JOIN it. (Or make it _correlated_, using WHERE clause condition(s) to the current selected row.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a @OneToMany relationship. If you are using Hibernate JPA, the best solution is to set the relation on entity level.

Take a look at this tutorial about how to use it:
 https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many